# 2 different syntax for variadic macros

Tags: c++, c, syntax, variadic-macros

```
#define TEST(X, ...)       X ## __VA_ARGS__    // (1)
#define TEST(X, args...)   X ## args           // (2)
```

Is there any *functional* difference between them ? (i.e. one of them can be used in a better way then other in certain cases). Also, are both the syntax included in C++11 ?

Answer (score 2):

The first syntax is standard C99 and also standard C++11. The second is, I believe, a GNU specific extension.

Comment: In C99, (2) gives you an error on gcc. I believe you meant a GNU **CPP** extension.

Comment: @Jesse: I'll certainly allow that (1) and (2) are handled by the preprocessor.  I'm not sure what you mean "In C99, (2) gives you an error on gcc."  Do you mean when compiling with `gcc --std=c99`?  Or are you compiling without the preprocessor altogether?

Comment: I belive you need `gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99` to produce `warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros`.